# How to remove xsi:nil="true using XMLBeans

Tags: xml, xsd, marshalling, xmlbeans, xml-nil

While using XMLBeans to generate XML ,

`xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"` gets
 inserted.

For example :

```
<element xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
```

But i need only `<element/>`

Please suggest .
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I can only suggest putting an empty (the default) value in the setter, leaving it null will result the nil thing, other way is that you can remove the nil attribute:

```
xnode.RemoveAttribute("nil", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
```

where xnode is the node that has the nil value.

hope that helps